# obtain fibonacci box from a pythagorean triple?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, pythagorean-triples

Given a pythagorean triple $(a, b, c)$, how can you get back the corresponding Fibonnaci box? Note the triple is not necessarily a primitive one, but if this simplifies the solution that is helpful too.

The inverse is well known. Given a Fibonnaci box:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
q & q'\\
p & p'\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $p = q' + q, p' = q + p$, then

$$
a = 2 q p\\
b = p' q'\\
c = p p' - q q' = q p' + q' p = q^2 + p^2 = p'^2 - 2 q p = q'^2 + 2 q p
$$

> **The question is**: how to get $q$, $q'$, $p$, $p'$ from $(a, b, c)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really looking for $q$ and $q'$ such that 
$$a=2pq=2q(q'+q)=2qq'+2q^2$$
and $$b=p'q'=(q+p)q'=(2q+q')q'=2qq'+q'^2.$$
We can also write  $b=u^2-v^2$ with $u=(q+q')$ and $v=q$, and then $a=2uv$ and $c=u^2+v^2$. From this, we readily recover $u^2=\frac{b+c}2$ and then $q=v=\frac a{2u}$. Ultimately, $q'=u-q$. Written explicitly (where $a$ is the more even leg of the triangle):
$$q=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2(b+c)}},\qquad q'=\frac{b+c-a}{\sqrt{2(b+c)}}. $$

Comment: Thank you. Can I take that "the more even" means "the even"?